# Are more specific selectors faster to parse?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a website:

```css
body#contact h1 {
  color: red;
}

#contact h1 {
  color: red;
}

body.contact h1 {
  color: red;
}

.contact h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="overrides.css">
</head>

<body id="contact" class="contact">
  <h1>Contact us!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Should I use line 1, 2, 3 or 4 in the css-file? They all do the same, but the last one potentially could select more than I intend. 
Does one have an advantage over the other when optimising for speed?

Comment: Perhaps this article can help? It includes a JS snippet to test selector speeds. It will vary on which browser you use though. https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/

Comment: Global selector `*` is known to be slower, together with attribute selector `[attr=val]`, for the rest, focus on readability, maintenance and functionality instead of worry about speed. And the lesser stuff to send to the browser the better, performance wise.

Comment: https://meiert.com/en/blog/performance-of-css-selectors-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we can say that specificity improves parse speed. What it does slightly improve is the render speed. There are other factors that affect your render speed, such as the CSS file size and having to many rules redefining the same class again and again e.g.

A couple of recommendations for improving your renders:

1. Define your basic rules for those elements you are going to use in general content (paragraphs, lists, bold, italics...). This way you'll overwrite the default browser CSS rules for them.
2. If there are rules not common for every `<li>` e.g., that are specific of a module, using the module parent class to define them will avoid the browser to crawl the whole HTML and you won't have to overwrite rules afterwards when you use the same tag for a different design piece.
3. If there are several levels of child nodes use classes for every of them that needs to be customised instead of adding more levels hanging of the parent class, otherwise you'll end with large chains of hierarchic classes when you need exceptions.
4. Try creating CSS modules that you can recycle across all your design applying a single class that define that modular element.
5. Avoid using * on its own if possible. Nowadays is not so much problem as it was 20 years ago, but the more specific the better for speed.
6. Don't abuse of :before and :after, use them responsibly. This are pseudo-elements that modify the DOM on the fly and sometimes, some browsers do not render them properly.
7. Try using CSS shorthands as a general rule.
8. If you use baground patterns, balance image size and repeat frequency. Create a pattern of 40px png or gif instead of using the minimum size of 4px e.g. as the browser will have to render the image 10 times less which worth the small extra file size.
9. Use sprites for icons an similar elements but not too big. You can make an sprite per color. I also recommend to do it vertically, all in a column. That way you can find icons easily using something like `background-position-y: calc(-8 * $module)`. This method will save you a lot of css rules to define the position and also HTML elements as you won't have to cluster the bg images in both axis (x,y)
10. If you are using  tags always add `with` and `height` attributes inline. And if those images are .jpg use a compression of about 60 and saved as progressive jpg.

I think with this basic rules you won't have any render problem in most of the cases.

```css
h1 {
  margin: 16px 8px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #999966;
}
p {
  margin: 8px 8px 16px;
}
.thumnnail {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
.content, aside {
  display: table-cell;
  }
.content {
  width: 75%;
}
.content ul {
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px 16px ;
}
.content li {
  margin:8px 0;
}
.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}
.tab {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 8px;
}
.tab + .tab {
  border-top: solid 2px #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="content">
  <h1>My title</h1>
  <img class="thumnnail" src="https://fakeimg.pl/250x100/" title="my image"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat</li>
    <li>non proident sunt in culpa</li>
    <li>qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
  </ul>
</section>
<aside>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab">Tab 1</li>
    <li class="tab">Tab 2</li>
    <li class="tab">Tab 3</li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shorter the selector, the better. If possible, make sure that the key selector is a class or an ID to keep it fast and specific.

For more Information please read below article. Highly recommended.

https://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-css-id-selectors-and-other-myths/

Comment: The shortest selector is * and it is the absolute worst :D

Answer (score 0):

Before you read my answer, I would like to tell you that optimizing speed via CSS code is a large problem-space. You can optimize the speed by using a minifier and minimizing the size of your CSS. That would ease the loading of the file at server side and sending it to the internet (to all browsers which request it) and on browser side it would increase performance by decreasing the file it has to download. Apart from this aspect, CSS code performance is strictly browser-level problem and you should only work on it if you observe client-side performance problems.

Also, before you do any optimization of your CSS, please test first by removing the rules for `h1` and see whether that makes a difference in performance.

In this answer I will assume that you have client-side performance issues when the browser runs your CSS. The `id` selector of `#` tells the browser to search for a given `id` and, since in the case of valid HTML code the `id` is unique, most browsers will stop searching at its first occurrence. However, you define the `id` for `body`, which is not increasing performance by too much, since `body` is direct child of the root `html` tag. If you have a section where all your `h1` tags are to be found, then it would be great if you gave an `id` to it and use it in your selector. `class` selectors will not stop at first match, since a `class` is not assumed to be unique. Let's assume that you have a `div` where all your `h1` tags are inside:

```
<div>
    <!-- There are some h1 tags in here -->
</div>
```

If you give it an `id`:

```
<div id="h1-container">
    <!-- There are some h1 tags in here -->
</div>
```

and use it in your selector:

```
#h1-container h1 {
    /*Your rules*/
}
```

then it should be pretty quick. If you still experience performance issues, then you will need to give us more information about your problem, possibly with a reproducible example, like a JSFiddle.